# javascript : Remove item from list of dictionary with name

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

How to Remove item from list of dict based on list of names

`arr1 = [{name:'item0',value:0},{name:'item1',value:1},{name:'item2',value:2},{name:'item3',value:3}`

`itemsToRemove = ['item1','item2']`

expected Output

`arr1 = [{name:'item0',value:0},{name:'item3',value:3}]`

tried to splice but doesn't work

`arr1.splice(columnsToRemove[1],1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.filter()` to clean it.

```js
let arr1 = [{name:'item0',value:0},{name:'item1',value:1},{name:'item2',value:2},{name:'item3',value:3}];

const itemsToRemove = ['item1','item2'];

arr1 = arr1.filter(obj => !itemsToRemove.includes(obj.name));

console.log(arr1);
```